# Mockito throwing WrongTypeOfReturnValue

Tags: java, mockito

Logic in implementation class is as shown below, I tried to write a mock and get exception as WrongTypeOfReturnValue

```
  /**
     * update audit and courier log when Provider sign the document.
     * @param cmsCourierInfo
     * @param documentInfo
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public boolean doAuditProviderESignCompletion(CMSCourierInfo cmsCourierInfo, DocumentInfo documentInfo) throws  Exception {

        String signerTitle = "";
        List<ParticipantInfo> participantInfos = documentInfo.getParticipants().getParticipantInfo();
        //First participant is Provider
        ParticipantInfo participantInfo = participantInfos.get(0);

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(participantInfo.getTitle())){
            signerTitle = participantInfo.getTitle();
        }
        //update audit log with provider signed information
        CMSCourierContractManager.signContract(cmsCourierInfo.getGuidString(), participantInfo.getName(), signerTitle, null);

        //update audit log when document sent to Internal Signer
        return doAuditSentForInternalSigner(cmsCourierInfo.getDocumentKey(), documentInfo);
    }
```

Test

```
   @Test
   public void testUpdateContractStatus() throws Exception{

        String documentKey = "TestKey";
        cmsCourierInfo = mock(CMSCourierInfo.class);
        when(cmsFactoryManager.findCourier(anyString())).thenReturn(cmsCourierInfo);
        EchoSignDocumentServiceImpl echoSignDocumentService = spy(documentService);
        when(echoSignDocumentService.updateContractStatus(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(echoSignDocumentService).updateContractStatus(anyString());
        boolean status = echoSignDocumentService.updateContractStatus(documentKey);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, status);
    }
```

Error that I get is

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by findCourier()
findCourier() should return CMSCourierInfo
***

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.


at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Some inputs will be of great help

Answer (score 4):

I can't explain the specific error you get (I would maybe have to see more of the code).  But there is definitely a coding error in the test.  Right before you invoke `updateContractStatus()`, you tell the mock to thrown an exception whenever this method is called with any string value.  Therefore, you will never get the return value assigned and will never reach the assert statement.

Also because I can't see all of your code I am just guessing, but based on the posted error help message, you might try changing the stubbing of your spy class to the form:

```
doReturn(true).when(echoSignDocumentService).updateContractStatus(anyString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you are clearly in the second case of the error message: you are stubbing a spy (echoSignDocumentService) with the when-then instead of the doReturn-when syntax

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to write `eq()`:

```
given(repository.getTitle(eq(variable))).willReturn(title)
```